# More precision needed from SQL Server Money data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, sqldatatypes, currency

I am working on this old SQL Server database which store numeric values in `MONEY` datatype. This has been good for years, now for some currency rate conversions we need up to 10 decimal places. We are exploring the possible conversion from `MONEY` datatype to `DECIMAL`.

I see that a `MONEY` field is equivalent to a `DECIMAL(19, 4)`. Would it be safe just use a broader `DECIMAL(25, 10)` to accommodate 10 decimal digits?

What if we want ensure more space for future request, what would be the limit that would not fit anymore the Classic ASP application built on the database (using `Double` datatype)?

Thanks

Comment: wow... this is a really cool problem. what currency are you working with that you need 10 decimal places?

Comment: 1 JPY = 0.00810349 USD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should define the type as decimal(25,10) which could hold the federal deficit up to an accuracy of 10 digits. (25 digits with ten after the decimal place).

Comment: Except that the Classic ASP double data type can only handle 15 significant digits.

Comment: What could be a better solution then @Dijkgraaf ?

Comment: Don't use classic ASP ;-) Maybe use ASP.NET where you have the decimal type which has 29 significant digits.

Comment: A double is a scientific number. It has an exponent and mantissa and is great for science but will round very differently then decimal.